# ImageView zooms on first tap

Tags: android, imageview, zooming

I am using a library to zoom in and out within a ImageView. I am using PhotoAttacher. When I click on the ImageView then first the ImageView loads in a fullscreen (within a dialog), and that is fine. But during loading in fullscreen mode the zoom function already takes place. How can I avoid zooming when I click first on ImageView. Here the code:

```
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog nagDialog = new Dialog(DetailView.this,
                        android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
                nagDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                nagDialog.setCancelable(false);
                nagDialog.setContentView(R.layout.preview_image);
                Button btnClose = (Button) nagDialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.btnIvClose);

                ivPreview = (ImageView) nagDialog
                        .findViewById(R.id.iv_preview_image);

                // Loading image from url in ImageView    
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(path)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.loading).into(ivPreview);

                // Here definition of zoom function
                PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(ivPreview);
                mAttacher.canZoom();

                btnClose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        nagDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                nagDialog.show();

            }

        });
```

The weird thing is, when I close the preview and click again on the imageview then it does not zoom in first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement the PhotoViewAttacher after they image is loaded successfully.

You add a callback to know if the request is successfully done.

Sample code:

```
 Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(path)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading).into(ivPreview, new Callback(){
         @Override
          public void onSuccess()
          {
                Log.d("Test picasso", "image loaded");
                PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(ivPreview);
                mAttacher.canZoom();
          }

          @Override
          public void onError()
          {
              Log.d("Test picasso", "image error");
          }
  });
```

Be aware, the Callback param is a [strong reference](http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#into-android.widget.ImageView-com.squareup.picasso.Callback-) and will prevent your Activity or Fragment from being garbage collected. So you should invoke an adjacent Picasso.cancelRequest(android.widget.ImageView) call to prevent temporary leaking.

Comment: where should I invoke cancelRequest? After success?

Comment: I think you can do inside the onDestroy() method, before your activity of fragment get garbage collected.